# Can't Sum a New Data In MySQL After Inner Join

Tags: mysql

Got some problem after using inner join, this is my query

```
> insert into total(ID,Grade) select midsemester.ID,(midsemester.grade +
> endsemester.grade) as total from midsemester inner join endsemester on
> midsemester.ID = endsemester.ID
```

This is the table:

**Table name: midsemester**

> ### ID  Grade
>
> 1        10 
>   2        30 
>   3        40

**Table name: endsemester**

> ### ID   Grade
>
> 1        30 
>   2        40 
>   3        20

and i need to sum these table to new table called total. This is the results that i was hoping.

**Table name: total**

> ### ID   Grade
>
> 1        40 
>   2         70 
>   3         60

I actually just need to sums up the grade's value using the id for the 3rd table. And tried several times using inner join, it's working. But when I try to insert a new data, the table of total can't sum a new data. Would appreciate any help, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you wang `union all` with an aggregation:

```
insert into total(ID,Grade)
    select ID, sum(grade) as total
    from (select id, grade from midsemester union all
          select id grade from endsemester
         ) me
    group by id;
```

However, this is a bad structure for the grades. You should store them all in one table, with a column indicating whether the grade is "midsemester" or "endsemester".